# How to setup router with 2 web connections starlink / comcast - to load balance

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, subnet

My goal is to have 2 internet connections load-balanced providing internet to my network.
WAN1: Comcast - Router (in bridge mode currently) connecting to peplink router/load balancer WAN1 port.

WAN2: Starlink(WiFi) `192.168.1.1-100` / `255.255.255.0` subnet.. that WiFi signal is grabbed by another wifi extender (which creates also a WiFi).. and that extender has an ethernet port which then connects to the WAN2 port of the Peplink load balancer.

Anyway at least that's the plan. Here are my questions. As of now, Starlink Wifi, the Extender that grabs that wifi signal, plus the Peplink router are all on 192.168.1...  setup as IP addresses. Also DHCP.. Starlink the extender and Peplink router all have DHCP.

I read somewhere that different networks need different subnets. My questions are as follows:

1. Is it ok to leave the IP setups as is?  I would think not, wouldn't traffic collide if the same IP is handed out to different clients?
2. What should be the setup for DHCP, IP range, and subnets for  a) Starlink-Wifi, b) Starlink-WiFi-Extender (which grabs the wifi traffic to put it into an ethernet cable)  and c) the Peplink T
   two router/load balancer.
3. Final question so WAN1 is Comcast in bridge mode (feeding into the Peplink router WAN1 which is setup as use DHCP - I assume that's ok?) - but how should WAN2 Starlink be setup on the Peplink router -right now it uses DHCP.. which gets IP from the extender (via ethernet cable) and gets internet through that.

Would appreciate some guidance. Should Starlink wifi be on a different subnet than the Peplink router? (I can't change the subnet for Starlink-extender, I assume it just takes the one from Starlink WiFi).

Comment: please create a schematic of your network for layers 1-3, it's difficult to follow just text.

Comment: note, 192.168.1.1-100 is not a 24 bit network (255.255.255.0), something is wrong here!

Answer (score 1):

If you want load balance, all traffic needs to go through the peplink router which then essentially - in layman's terms - "terminates" the "Starlink network". So separate networks don't matter as long you don't use multiple instances of the same IP.

If you want to access one of the WANs bypassing the balancer, separate networks (not just different subnets) are needed if they have their own DHCPs (since only one DHCP is allowed on a network). Once the networks are separated it doesn't matter if you use the same or different subnets.